# Redirect a subdomain to another but don't change the address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I want to redirect `subdomain1.domain.com` to `subdomain2.domain.com` but without changing the addres in the address bar.

Is this possible via .htaccess? If not, what will be an alternative solution (I'm using cPanel)?

I don't want to use a proxy ([P])!!!

Comment: if you don't want to use [P] then, via htaccess, you can't

Comment: Why the downwote? Plese describe what's the problem with this question.

@Yazmat: Thank you for you reply. I realized that I can't do this via .htaccess without proxy. Still looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the 2 subdomains share a document root (or one is in a subdirectory of the other), then you can't do it without a proxy of any kind, with a `[P]` in htaccess or setting up a reverse proxy using `ProxyPass` (note that both use mod_proxy). There's no alternative solution that's strictly apache. You could write a script to load the pages of the other subdomain and park it on the first subdomain, but that's proxying as well, you're better off just using mod_proxy or one of it's extensions (like mod_proxy_html), which handles internal url rewrites of redirect locations, and cookies. An example of a non-apache solution would be mounting one subdomain's document root into the other and using mod_rewrite.